# Создание массива структур на C

Tags: c

Создаю динамический массив структур, но код не работает, а выдает рандомное число на выходе. Подскажите, где может быть ошибка. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person{
    int h;
    int k;
};


int ReadArray(FILE* file, struct person* data, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(fscanf(file, "%d", data[i].h) != 1){
            return -1;
        }
        if(fscanf(file, "%d", data[i].k) != 1){
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(void){
    FILE* fin;
    struct person* data;
    int size;
    struct person* result;

    if((fin = fopen("input.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(fin, "%d", &size) != 1){
        printf("Can't read size!\n");
        fclose(fin);
        return -1;
    }

    if(size < 1){
        printf("Incorrect size!\n)");
        fclose(fin);
        return -1;
    }

    if((data = (struct person*) malloc(size * sizeof(struct person))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(fin);
        return -1;
    }

    if((result = (struct person*) malloc(size * sizeof(struct person))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(fin);
        return -1;
    }

    if(ReadArray(fin, data, size) < 0){
        printf("Can't read array!\n");
        free(data);
        fclose(fin);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(fin);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d %d/n", result[i].h, result[i].k);
    }


}
```

Comment: Подскажите, что значит "не работает"... *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*

Comment: при запуске выдает рандомное число. видимо я ошибся при выделении памяти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вы забыли, что передавать для чтения надо адрес:

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &data[i].h) != 1)
```

А закончим тем, что читаете-то вы в массив `data`

```
ReadArray(fin, data, size)
```

а выводите — массив `result`

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    printf("%d %d/n", result[i].h, result[i].k);
}
```

Так и вспоминается анекдот "Мариванна, я уже столько воды выпил — скоро ус..сь, а Петров все икает и икает!" :)